# Is this discontinuous integral valid?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dM}{dt}=-(\lambda_1+f(t)\lambda_2)M$$

Where $f(t)$ is either $1$ or $0$. I'm not sure what the mathematical term for this is, but $f(t)$ has no infinitesimally thin peaks, i.e. if $f(t_0)=1$ then $f(t_0-\delta t)=1$ and/or $f(t_0+\delta t)=1$.

Following 'normal' integration rules and setting the boundary condition $M(t=0)=M_0$, I end up with:

$$M(t)=M_0e^{-\left(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 \int_0^t f(\tau)\ d\tau\right)}$$

Solving this equation numerically shows that this is probably correct. But is this integral analytically correct? Is the integral $\int_0^t f(\tau)\ d\tau$ well defined?

Comment: As the question is currently phrased your choice of $f$ is limited to either $\forall t \: : \: f(t) = 1$ or $\forall t \: : \: f(t) = 0$. Why is that? You do not limit $\delta t$ and the natural assumption is that $\delta t$ can be any real number. Clearly, this is not what you mean. Answering your question requires measure theory.

Comment: Perhaps I did an awful job of explaining what I meant, but f(t) is basically like a bunch of boxcar-like functions in a row.

Comment: I recommend that you *edit* your question and include the exact formula for at least one specific example of $f$. What you describe sound like a square wave in signal analysis.